# Semantic UI Dropdown shows empty

Tags: semantic-ui

In a basic example I cannot get the Dropdown in Semantic UI to show up correctly.  I have included the entire file as I have no idea what I am doing wrong.  Just trying to get the drop box to show up.  Thanks!

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.9/semantic.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.9/semantic.min.js"></script>
</head>

<html>
    <div class="ui selection dropdown">
        <select name="gender" id="gender-select" class="ui search selection dropdown">
            <option value="male">Male</option>
            <option value="female">Female</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</html>

<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#gender-select').dropdown();
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that your code contains dropdown within dropdown `ui dropdown`, try to remove the parent div.

```
<html>
<select name="gender" id="gender-select" class="ui search selection dropdown">
            <option value="male">Male</option>
            <option value="female">Female</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
</html>
```